# How to trigger a event to wpf application on insert of ms access

Tags: c#, wpf, events, ms-access

I have 3rd party application which is in `.net` in font end and `MS Access` as data base.
when user input some data from `.net` application it stores the data in `Ms access` database.Now I have to create another application which read data from **MS access** on every **insert query**.
I have 2 option in which i can i.e. 
**1.Timer with minimum time Interval

2.File Watcher that monitor on .mdb file**
other then these two is there any option to implement this if yes then ho can I?

Comment: You might try creating a data macro that launches some external notification http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx#_Toc264895168 There are restrictions on data macros so this may not be possible, however.

Comment: thanks For Your Reply. I have no access over the application which updates the **MS access ** database. Now tell From where I can call or include that Macro

Answer (score 1):

You should create a data access layer in your application so that that is the only layer accessing the database.

Instead of having an architecture where the UI communicates directly with the database:

**UI <--> DB**

A data layer:

**UI <--> DL <--> DB**

This way you can make your data layer make whatever decisions you need it to be without going into guesswork about what the database management system is doing and when.

Comment: thanks @Paulo For Your Reply. I have no access over the application which updates the **MS access ** database